# MATCH .. AGAINST .. не ищет некоторые слова

Tags: mysql, поиск

Пользуюсь для поиска на сайте данной конструкцией. Использую режим IN BOOLEAN MODE. Некоторые слова не находятся, хотя они точно имеются в базе. Ограничение на минимальное количество символов повлиять не может, так как искомые слова больше этого ограничения. Да и другие слова такой же длины находятся без проблем. Место нахождения в ячейке тоже не имеет значения, так одно слово в определенном месте находится, а другое нет. Кодировка базы utf-8, все данные записаны латиницей, как и искомое слово.

Примеры таких слов: "know", "you", "best"...

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: немножко не по теме: а зачем поиск базы использовать? может проще будет прикрутить поисковую систему и пользоваться ею? например, [spinxsearch](http://sphinxsearch.com/). Тогда поиск быстрее будет проходить + всякие плюшки получите

Comment: Уже тоже прихожу к такой мысли. Но больше ради спортивного интереса хочется разобратся, в чем проблема)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорей всего, вы попали в [Full-Text Stopwords](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-stopwords.html). Для myisam ваши приведённые слова "know", "you", "best" как раз есть в дефолтном списке.

Эти слова вообще не попадают в полнотекстовый поиск - слов в индексе нет, поэтому полнотекстовый поиск их и не может найти, хоть даже и boolean mode.

Чтобы изменить этот список, добавьте параметр `ft_stopword_file` с пустым значением (или с путём до списка слов, которые вам не нужны) в файл конфигурации `mysql`, перезапустите СУБД и пересоздайте fulltext-индексы.

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Очень помогли